# How to iterate an integer in for-range loop in Go 1.22?

Tags: go, language-lawyer

Go 1.22 has been released today. According to [the release note](https://go.dev/doc/go1.22#),

> "For" loops may now range over integers. For [example](https://go.dev/play/p/ky02zZxgk_r?v=gotip):
>
> ```golang
> package main
>
> import "fmt"
>
> func main() {
>     for i := range 10 {
>         fmt.Println(10 - i)
>     }
>     fmt.Println("go1.22 has lift-off!")
> }
> ```
>
> See the spec for [details](https://go.dev/ref/spec#For_range).

I want to learn the details but it seems the spec doesn't explain about the syntax at all.

I added `#language-lawyer` tag as I want strict understandings.

Comment: https://tip.golang.org/ref/spec#For_range — the spec on the main site hasn't been updated yet, as you can see it's dated August 2, 2023.

Comment: Note: closing this question as "Seeking recommendations" is invalid. Leaving aside that this post does *not* directly ask for external resources, asking for *official* documentation or specifications about some feature is on-topic.

Answer (score 6):

Today (2024/02/08), [the spec](https://go.dev/ref/spec#For_range) has been updated to the latest version.

According to the spec, the only syntax allowed is this:

```golang
for i := range n {
    //...
}
```

- `n` is a (possibly untyped) integer expression.
- It iterates from `0` to `n - 1`. (`n` is exclusive.)
- If `n <= 0`, the loop iterates nothing.
- Only one loop variable can be specified. (`for i, j := 10` is (naturally) invalid.)
- Unlike in Python, you cannot specify a step or iterate in reverse order.

---

Example:

[playground](https://go.dev/play/p/3yrM8vLfgZb?v=gotip)

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    for i := range 5 {
        fmt.Println(i) //=> 0 1 2 3 4
    }

    var i int
    for i = range 1 + 2 {
        fmt.Println(i) //=> 0 1 2
    }

    for i := range 0 {
        fmt.Println(i) //compiles but not executed
    }

    for i := range -1 {
        fmt.Println(i) //compiles but not executed
    }
}
```